# I get different result from Graphql playground and front-end

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

I am using graphql and Vue.js and apollo

Here is my DateBank

```json
const sensorsdb = [
{
    name: "sensor 1",
    id: "s-1",
    timestamp: 1582021371,
    value: 100
},
{
    name: "sensor 1",
    id: "s-1",
    timestamp: 1579451703,
    value: 150
},
{
    name: "sensor 2-1",
    id: "s-2-1",
    timestamp: 1582021371,
    value: 200
},
{
    name: "sensor 2-2",
    id: "s-2-2",
    timestamp: 1579451703,
    value: 350
},
{
    name: "sensor 2-2",
    id: "s-2-2",
    timestamp: 1582021371,
    value: 300
},
{
    name: "sensor 3",
    id: "s-3",
    timestamp: 1582021371,
    value: 400
},];
```

I want to get all objects according to object id. sensorId is an array. because I want to get multiple objects with multiple ids.

The following is my API function to get object.

```js
async getDataById({ sensorId }) {
    let sensorsData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sensorId.length; i++) {
        let sensorData = this.sensorDataStore.sensors.filter(sensor => sensor.id === sensorId[i]);
        sensorsData = sensorsData.concat(sensorData);
    }
    return sensorsData;
}
```

In Front-end, gql file is following:

```js
query sensorData($id: [String]){
sensorData(id: $id){
    name
    id
    value
    timestamp
}}
```

and with my apollo query code in vue.js, in this case selectedSensorId is ["s-2-1", "s-2-2"]

```html
<ApolloQuery :query="require('../graphql/sensorDataById.gql')" :variables="{ id: selectedSensorId }">
  <template v-slot="{ result: { loading, error, data } }">
    <b-loading :is-full-page=true :active.sync=loading :can-cancel="false"/>
    <div v-if="error">
      <no-data-error />
    </div>
    <div v-if="data">
      {{ data }}
      <bar-chart-view :sensorInfo="data.sensorData"/>
    </div>
  </template>
</ApolloQuery>
```

But I got the following different result:
Graphql playground which has correct result
The front-end result with duplicated sensor-s-2
[image: Graphql playground which has correct result]

[image: The front-end result with duplicated sensor-s-2]

Answer (score 1):

Apollo Client normalizes results according to the `id` and `__typename` fields as described [in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#data-normalization). If an array returns multiple items with the same `id`, by default they will share the same cache key, which means what's returned by the client will be the same object.

You should provide a custom `dataIdFromObject` function to your `InMemoryCache` constructor that accommodates your specific use case. Something like:

```js
const dataIdFromObject = object => {
  switch (object.__typename) {
    case 'SensorDataPoint': return `SensorDataPoint:${object.id}:{value}`;
    default: return defaultDataIdFromObject(object);
  }
}
```

Note that if you use the same type elsewhere, you may experience issues with the cache updated correctly after mutations because we are now keying off both the `value` and `id`. You might want to consider a different approach to your schema where the ids are actually unique :

```json
type SensorDataPoint {
  id: ID!
  sensorId: ID!
  sensorName: String!
  value: Int!
  timestamp: Int!
}
```

or even better

```json
type SensorDataPoint {
  id: ID!
  value: Int!
  timestamp: Int!
  sensor: Sensor!
}

type Sensor {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it its been a while but what Daniel Rearden mentioned above, I included the `{ addTypename: false }` as options for InMemoryCache

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors)
        graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, extensions }) => {
          console.log(`[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Code: ${extensions?.code}`)
        })
      if (networkError) {
        console.log(`[Network error] ->: ${networkError}`)
        Toast.show('Connection Error', {
          position: Toast.positions.TOP,
          type: 'danger',
          duration: 3000,
        })
      }
    }),
    authMiddleware,
    link,
  ]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache({ addTypename: false }),
});
```